# estou fazendo um exercício de Javascript onde preciso retornar um numero recebido ao contrário e em um array

Tags: javascript, string, funções

Estou fazendo um exercício de Javascript onde preciso retornar um numero recebido ao contrário e em um array. porém dentro da função não consigo utilizar `.split()` e nem `toString()`, quando passo o mouse aparecem como `'any'`.

```js
function reverte(n) {
  let viraString = n.toString()
  return viraString.split('').reverse()
}
console.log(reverte(123456));
```

Fiz para teste basicamente o mesmo código fora da função e funcionou.

```js
let teste = 123456
let v = teste.toString()

let teste2 = v.split('').reverse()

console.log(teste2);
```

Comment: Coloquei o seus códigos como executáveis e ambos os fragmentos retornam o mesmo resultado portanto não sendo possível reproduzir o erro alegado com as informações fornecidas na pergunta. Está exibindo `ANY`, talvez esteja usando Typescript ao invés de Javascript, verifique. Não publique nada que não seja tecnicamente relacionado com a pergunta, por exemplo cumprimento ou justificativas de qualidade. Para saber mais sobre o funcionamento do site visite nossa [help].

Answer (score -2):

No JavaScript, o tipo "any" é usado para representar um valor que pode ser de qualquer tipo.
O seu código não apresenta erro. Se você estiver usando VsCode, ao passar o mouse ele mostra o "any" pois quando o tipo não é declarado, ele assume que o tipo é "any", que nesse caso refere-se ao tipo do argumento que você passou:

`function reverte(n: any) {...}`

Isso começa a ficar mais claro quando começar usar TypeScript, mas por enquanto é isso.

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).